# CefSharp call page event

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

I want to fill submit form on a website page using cefSharp:

```
cefSharp1.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('Author').value='Me'");
```

But button `submit` not active, because this form checks if keys have been pressed, there are attached events: `main.keyup=onTextChange($event,index,id)`
how can i simulate call them? Thanks.

Comment: You should add some more tags e.g. JavaScript to get help from a wider audience.

Comment: amaitland done. thanks.

Comment: You can try simulate a key press using something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/59113178/4583726 or execute some javascript to remove the validation entirely. Alternatively you can try sending individual key presses like https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/79/CefSharp.OffScreen.Example/Program.cs#L86 you need to ensure the browser has focus

Comment: Your answer helped me. Big thanks friend!

Comment: Great, you can post your own answer to help others.